# Possible to include code based on the existence of a class?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, c-preprocessor

I have created a code generator for our project to generate a lot of our crud operations, and basic dataAccess objects for our database.  (we aren't using some other tools because we aren't allowed to execute dynamic sql and are only allowed stored procs).

The thing I am thinking about right now is that we have ~1,200 tables.  I don't want to include every table object into our project (not until it is actually going to be used).

My objects contain a property that references other objects (like a parent/child relationship).

Say I have my 2 objects (they are in different files)

```
public class ClassA{
  public ClassB GetClassBforA{get;set;}
  //Lost of other properties and code
}

public class ClassB{/* bunch of stuff*/}
```

Now I know no one is currently using ClassB, and I don't want to include in our project (yet) because it has many references to other classes and tools.  I would like the property on ClassA to not be compiled.  (since this file is automatically generated it is bound to be over written)

I was thinking of maybe something like this

```
public class ClassA{
  #if ClassBIsDefind
  public ClassB GetClassBforA{get;set;}
  #endif
  //Lost of other properties and code
}


#define ClassBIsDefind
public class ClassB{/* bunch of stuff*/}
```

But this doesn't work because ClassBIsDefind is set in another file.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Take a look at already existing free code generation tools like Live T4 Templates provided by ReSharper, also Visual STudio provides templates feature. Perhaps it worth to reuse rather than invent a wheel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define conditional code compilation symbols in the Build tab of the project properties page in Visual Studio, or with a command line switch if you invoke the compiler at the command line.  These symbols are available to all files.

Comment: Fair enough; I just wanted to address the OP's comment that "... this doesn't work because ClassBIsDefind is set in another file."

Comment: This is a possible solution, but it doesn't seem as "easy" as I would like it to be (I know, not everything can be easy).

Comment: I know there is a way to define symbols in the build tab, and there is also a way to pass /define:symbleName to the compiler.  Is there a way to define a symbolFile and pass it to the compiler.

Comment: I think I might go this route.  I'm going to build a parser that when run will find all my AutoGenerated Objects (AGOs) that are included in the project, and add the symbol to the project file.  This tool will have to be run whenever new files are added that are AGOs, but the user will still not have to manually edit the project file.

Now I just wonder how much work it is to get VS2010 to provide a link for the project to run this tool.

Answer (score 1):

Only generate code for the tables that *are* being used.

Comment: This might just be the answer.  I was hoping I could use a way that doesn't require me to maintain a "Object Is Used" type of list.

Answer (score 0):

You can load the type dynamically by calling **[`Activator.CreateInstance()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.activator.createinstance.aspx)**, and catch the exception that occurs if the type doesn't exist.